# Method signature in ASP.NET Core for AngularJS API request with JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following API request:

```js
var answeredQuestions = {};
$scope.GetNextQuestion = function (question, value) {

    answeredQuestions[question] = value;
    var data = {
    };
    data["currentStep"] = $scope.currentStep;
    data["answeredQuestions"] = answeredQuestions;

    $http.post("/api/WizardAPI/GetNextQuestion", JSON.stringify(data))
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.currentStep = data.data;
        }, OnError);
};
```

This is the API controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetNextQuestion")]
public IActionResult GetNextQuestion([FromBody]string currentStep)
{
    return Ok("test");
}
```

However, "currentstep" is always empty.
If I change the data type to object I get something, so the API call is working.
I tried mapping it to a custom class, but then the API call fails.

Here's the class:

```cs
public class data
{
    public string CurrentStep { get; set; }
    public string[,] AnsweredQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to handle this JSON?

Request payload

```
{"currentStep":"ERP","answeredQuestions":{"ERP":1}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample request payload? Meanwhile, I suspect this `string[,] AnsweredQuestions` is incorrect. `[,]` is known as a multidimensional array. Are you sending `answeredQuestions` as multidimensional array ? Or just an array? If just an array, use `List<string> AnsweredQuestions`.

Comment: Here's the request payload:
{"currentStep":"ERP","answeredQuestions":{"ERP":1}}

Comment: Okay, The `AnsweredQuestions` should be `Dictionary<string, int>` as it is a key-value pair. And change the method as: `public IActionResult GetNextQuestion([FromBody]data @data)`. Suggest to name the `data` class with PascalCase as best practice.

Comment: This works if my answer is an int, but what if my answer is a string?
If I just change it to Dictionary<string, string> it doesn't take the first answer which is 1 (int)

Comment: Then you need `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` for the value with `dynamic` type. Then to get the value from dictionary, you need to perform safe cast, depend on your situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed based on your request payload, the `AnsweredQuestions` type should be: `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

And it is suggested to name the class as PascalCase as C# naming convention.

```cs
public class Data
{
    public string CurrentStep { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> AnsweredQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Change your `GetNextQuestion` API method as:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetNextQuestion")]
public IActionResult GetNextQuestion([FromBody] Data data)
{
    ...
}
```